# Use different Logs in waf

Tags: waf

I added a custom logger to the waf build command as seen below. The output of this `wscript` is shown below.

But I want to have the *normal* waf logger to print on the terminal, and the normal + custom logger output to be written to the log file. Is this possible? The problem is, that the *normal* output is most times sufficient, and the added verbosity by the custom logger slows down the build quite a lot.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

top = '.'
out = 'build'

VERSION = '0.0.0'
APPNAME = 'app'

from waflib import Configure, Logs
import logging

Configure.autoconfig = True

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_c')
    conf.path.make_node('main.c').write(
        '#include <stdio.h>\n\nint main(int argc, char* argv[]) {\n    return 0;\n}\n')

def build(bld):
    import sys
    import os
    log_file = os.path.join(out, 'build.log')
    bld.logger = Logs.make_logger(log_file, out)
    hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    bld.logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    bld.program(target='app', source='main.c')
```

The produced output is like this:

```
$ python waf
Configuring the project
Setting top to                           : /cygdrive/d/log
Setting out to                           : /cygdrive/d/log/build
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
Waf: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/log/build'
[1/2] Compiling main.c

['/usr/bin/gcc', '../main.c', '-c', '-o/cygdrive/d/log/build/main.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking build/app.exe

['/usr/bin/gcc', '-Wl,--enable-auto-import', 'main.c.1.o', '-o/cygdrive/d/log/build/app.exe', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic']
Waf: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/log/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.473s)
```

What I need is a terminal output like this:

```
[1/2] Compiling main.c
[2/2] Linking build/app.exe
```

and a log file output like this:

```
[1/2] Compiling [32mmain.c[0m

['/usr/bin/gcc', '../main.c', '-c', '-o/cygdrive/d/log/build/main.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking [33mbuild/app.exe[0m

['/usr/bin/gcc', '-Wl,--enable-auto-import', 'main.c.1.o', '-o/cygdrive/d/log/build/app.exe', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic']
```

Bonus: How can the non printable characters be removed **only** in the log file output?